# Complex Numbers $e^{(z+i)/z}=1-i$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

can someone help me solving this equation?. I tried to resolve it by logarithms but i got stuck in the process.

$$e^{(z+i)/z}=1-i$$

That's what i have:

$$ \frac{z+1}{z}=L(1-i)$$
$$(z+i)=zL(1-i)$$

Comment: Where in the process did you get stuck?

Comment: It would help if you showed your work so we might be more able to point out mistakes or hints

Comment: Well $1-i = e^{i\frac {3\pi}2}$ so $\frac {z+i}z = i\pi(\frac 32 + 2k)$ and $z + i = zi\pi(\frac 32 + 2k)$ and $\frac iz = i\pi(\frac 32 + 2k) - 1$ etc..  Can you solve that?

Comment: @fleablood  $1-i = 1+e^{i\frac {3\pi}2}$ or $1-i = \sqrt 2e^{-i\frac {\pi}4}$

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that.....  Same idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote $z+i =zL(1-i).$ From that you get $i = -z + zL(1-i) = z(-1+L(1-i)).$

Dividing both sides by $-1+L(1-i),$ you get $\dfrac i {-1 + L(1-i)} = z.$

Can you do something with that?

Answer (score 2):

$1-i = \sqrt{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}4}$

So $z + i = -zi\ln{\sqrt{2}}(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)$

$z(1 + i\ln{\sqrt{2}}(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)) = i$

$z = \frac{i}{1 + i\ln{\sqrt{2}}(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)}$

$ = \frac{i(1- i\ln{\sqrt{2}}(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi))}{1+(\ln{\sqrt{2}})^2(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)^2}$

$ = \frac{\ln{\sqrt{2}}(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)+i}{1+(\ln{\sqrt{2}})^2(\frac {\pi}4 + 2k\pi)^2}$

Unless I made some arithmetical error which I nearly always do.

Comment: Actually, I think surrounding and pulverizing the problem and grinding it to dust isn't really as good as something like the incomplete answer that I wrote.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Your answer is better.